# Pasar código MySQL a generador de consultas de Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

Buenas tardes, tengo un inconveniente al tratar de pasar un query que funciona bien al introducirlo en phpMyAdmin. Pero cuando lo trato de escribir como una consulta en un controller con Yii2 no hace nada.¿Como podría pasar el código?

Este es en sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(c.NOMBRE,' ',c.APELLIDO_PATERNO,' ',c.APELLIDO_MATERNO) AS NOMBRE_CANDIDATO
FROM tbl_candidatos c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  FK_CANDIDATO, count(PK_VACANTES_CANDIDATOS) AS Num_Vacantes 
            FROM tbl_vacantes_candidatos
                GROUP BY FK_CANDIDATO) nc 
                ON nc.FK_CANDIDATO = c.PK_CANDIDATO
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_vacantes_candidatos
            WHERE FK_VACANTE = 164
            AND FK_CANDIDATO = nc.FK_CANDIDATO);
```

Y esto en Yii2 y no funciona:

```
$dataProvider2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        'CONCAT(c.NOMBRE," ", c.APELLIDO_PATERNO, " ",c.APELLIDO_MATERNO) AS NOMBRE'
    ])
    ->from('tbl_candidatos as c')
    ->leftJoin('tbl_vacantes_candidatos vc','select FK_CANDIATO count(PK_VACANTES_CANDIDATOS) AS Num_Vacantes
        FROM tbl_vacantes_candidatos GROUP BY FK_CANDIDATO nc','nc.FK_CANDIDATO = c.PK_CANDIDATO')
    ->where('NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM tbl_vacantes_candidatos WHERE FK_VACANTE = $vacantes AND FK_CANDIATO = nc.FK_CANDIATO)')
    ->distinct();
```

Comment: Qué error te marca o que es lo que pasa?

Comment: Al ver la información que trae manda esto en vez de la lista de personas que debería como en phpMyAdmin: 
dataProvider2
:
distinct
:
true
from
:
["tbl_vacantes_candidatos"]
groupBy
:
["FK_CANDIDATO"]
having
:
null
indexBy
:
null
join
:
[Array(3)]
limit
:
null
offset
:
null
orderBy
:
null
params
:
[]
select
:
(2) ["FK_CANDIDATO", "COUNT(PK_VACANTES_CANDIDATOS) AS Num_Vacantes"]
selectOption
:
null
union
:
null
where
:
null

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar una consulta en Yii2 tienes que ejecutar la consulta, esto es con `all()` o con `one()` (solo te trae uno), por lo que quedaría tu sentencia así

```
$dataProvider2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        'CONCAT(c.NOMBRE," ", c.APELLIDO_PATERNO, " ",c.APELLIDO_MATERNO) AS NOMBRE'
    ])
    ->from('tbl_candidatos as c')
    ->leftJoin('tbl_vacantes_candidatos vc','select FK_CANDIATO count(PK_VACANTES_CANDIDATOS) AS Num_Vacantes
        FROM tbl_vacantes_candidatos GROUP BY FK_CANDIDATO nc','nc.FK_CANDIDATO = c.PK_CANDIDATO')
    ->where('NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM tbl_vacantes_candidatos WHERE FK_VACANTE = $vacantes AND FK_CANDIATO = nc.FK_CANDIATO)')
    ->distinct()
    ->all();
```

Comment: No funciono hora no manda nada, pero igual gracias.

Comment: Pon bien, que haces un print_r? qué te manda?

Comment: Yo veo lo que manda el ajax desde la consola de firefox, tengo otros dataProvider que mandan bien la info. Ahora que puse lo que mencionaste manda el error 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: como menciono pega bien tu código, en ajax tienes que regresarlo encode, puede  que ahí esté el error